# Swiper.js | start autoplay slider only when user scrolls to slider view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, swiper.js

How to initialize autoplay slider only when the user switches to slider view. It should be done with jquery

I have 3 sliders on my page and I want to do all of them. Do you have any other solution?

```js
$(function(){
     var swipers = new Swiper(".category .swiper", {
        spaceBetween: 20,
        slidesPerView: 3,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: ".category-mains .swiper-button-right", 
          prevEl: ".category-mains .swiper-button-left"
        },
       });


     $(window).scroll(function () {
        
       if ($(document).scrollTop() > 600) {
         swipers.autoplay.start();
       } else {
         swipers.autoplay.stop();
       }
     });
});

// this didn't work
```

Answer (score 2):

Better than scroll try to use Intersection Observer API.
On load, you put an intersection observer listener on the class ".swipper", when a swipper intersect, you start the slider.
Check here explanation on Intersection Observer:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

It's really easy to implement and lot lot more efficient than onscroll.

Take just care intersect fire when element is in the view and when the element goes out of view.

Ok I've added a snippet:

```js
    /* ============== intersection observe Swiper ============== */
    const observerSwiper = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, self) {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            let elid;
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                elid = entry.target.id;
            }
            if (elid) {
                let elsSwiper = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper');
                elsSwiper.forEach((e) => {
                    if (e.id === elid) {
                        console.log(e.id + ' interesecting'); // play this swiper here
                    } else {
                        console.log(e.id + ' is not interesecting'); // stop other swiper
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }, {
        root: null,
        threshold: 0.75,
        rootMargin: '0px'
    });

    /* ============== intersection observe Swiper: init ============== */
    const initOberverReveal = () => {
        let elsSwiper = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper');
        elsSwiper.forEach((el) => {
            observerSwiper.observe(el);
        });
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', initOberverReveal);
```

```css
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    /**
     * 1. Remove the margin in all browsers (opinionated).
     * 2. For the body to fill the viewport
     */
    body {
        padding: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        margin: auto;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #333333;
        color: #EEEEEE;
    }

    header, section {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    section:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
    }

    .swiper {
        width: 75%;
        height: 75%;
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<header>
    header
</header>

<section id="section1">
    <div id="swiper1" class="swiper">
        swiper 1
    </div>
</section>

<section id="section2">
    <div id="swiper2" class="swiper">
        swiper 2
    </div>
</section>

<section id="section3">
    <div id="swiper3" class="swiper">
        swiper 3
    </div>
</section>
```

HTML and CSS, nothing special just for the demo to have element to intersect. For each swipers, you have a generic .swiper class and for each a different id.

**Javascript:**

initObserverReveal

this function is launched at windows load, select all the swiper class and put an "observe" on each.

observerSwiper

That the function observing.

The "threshold is here at 0.75, meaning when 75% of the swiper is visible it's intersecting. You can change to 1 (100%), to 0.25 (25%)... and so on.

If intersecting we take the ID of the intersecting swiper.

Next we loop through all swipers, if same as the intersecting you can play your swiper. Otherwise you can stop the others.

Comment: Can you help me how should I write the code part?